# Physical cache vs Logical cache

Tags: performance, caching, processor

What is the pros and cons of:
- Physical cache (between MMU and Memory)
- Logical cache (between CPU and MMU)

from a programmer's view? How to get the best of each of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google gives this [Link](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~weems/CmpSci635A/Lecture10/L10.31.html).

Up to date [Link](http://www.readorrefer.in/article/Logical-versus-physical-caches_7647/)

The article gives pros and cons of each type of caching system and states that both can be implemented at the same time.  Froma programmer's point of view, anytime I need not worry about virtual addressing and associated costs, its a win, but programming for cache hit/misses is going to affect performance much more than slight latency I believe.  This area is not my forte, coming from small embedded systems programming though where caching is just now starting to become relevent to what I do.

Comment: Fyi, the link you shared seems to be outdated..
A recent (as of 2017) link: http://www.readorrefer.in/article/Logical-versus-physical-caches_7647/

Answer (score 0):

Excellent book on the subject - [UNIX® Systems for Modern Architectures: Symmetric Multiprocessing and Caching for Kernel Programmers, By Curt Schimmel](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0201633388). You'll find detailed discussion of virtually vs. physically tagged caches and what [kernel] programmers have to do about them.